# Emotion Detection with FER2013 and MPI dataset using CNN and TFLearn

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, kaggle, vision, tflearn

I am just beginner for Deep Learning. I try to capture all details.

Perplex is derived from MPI dataset. other emotions are derived from FER2013. To balance the data set, all emotions into (training: 3171, validation: 816) strategy, due to lack of perplex dataset.

**Dataset Size:**

```
        perplex  happy   sad  neutral  angry
train     3171   3171   3171     3171   3171

        perplex  happy  sad  neutral  angry
test      816    816    816      816    815
```

FER2013 source: downsized version of

https://www.kaggle.com/msambare/fer2013

MPI source (only cam 2, 3 & 4 angle, of all actors emotions such as Clueless, Confusion and Thinking):

https://www.b-tu.de/en/graphic-systems/databases/the-small-mpi-facial-expression-database

https://www.b-tu.de/fg-graphische-systeme/datenbanken/die-grosse-mpi-gesichtsausdrueckedatenbank

**preprocess steps:**

Firstly, all 3171 x 5 = 15855 and 816 x 5 = 4079 images into 48x48 gray scale.

**Samples:**

[Sample dataset for Angry, Happy, Perplex and Sad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2peY.png)

**CNN Architecute using TFLearn:**

```
    # Input Layer
    convnet = input_data(name="input", shape=[None, 48, 48, 1])

    #Enabling Filters
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation = "relu")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation = "relu")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation = "relu")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation = "relu")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation = "relu")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation = "relu")
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.5)

    #Output Layer
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 5, activation = "softmax")
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer =  "SGD", learning_rate = 0.001, loss = "categorical_crossentropy", name = "targets")


model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, 
            best_checkpoint_path = best_cp_path + '/', 
            best_val_accuracy = "BEST_VAL_ACCURACY",
            tensorboard_dir = log_path, 
            tensorboard_verbose = 3)

image_size = 48
channel = 1

#Split for training and testing
train_x = np.array([index[0] for index in train]).reshape(-1, image_size, image_size, channel)

train_y = np.array([index[1] for index in train])

test_x = np.array([index[0] for index in test]).reshape(-1, image_size, image_size, channel)

test_y = np.array([index[1] for index in test])

model.fit(
            train_x,
            train_y, 
            validation_set = (test_x, test_y),
            n_epoch = 500,
            snapshot_step = 500,
            show_metric = True,
            run_id = "ED_SGD-0.001",
            snapshot_epoch = True
        )
```

I am shuffling all training and validation files before splitting as train and test input.

The training is overfitting after 150+ epoch out of 500, I am using raw SGD without momentum and learning decay, I tried Adam also same overfitting issue. the val_accuracy is 0.62 and train_accuracy is 0.8+

Early Saving Method: I am saving 0.62 accuracy model files in the model folder.

Odd's in my mind:

If you see closely all perplex emotion have black background, because it's taken in lab environment. Other emotions are taken from fer2013 it's lively with different grey shade background and some black also I can find.

1. **How to overcome this overfitting issue?**
2. **Which hyper-parameter values
   should I tune?**
3. **Should I upscale to 7000+ images as like in FER2013
   dataset?**
4. **Should I apply different background of grey shades randomly to perplex
   images?**
5. **How to increase the accuracy?**

Loss curve:

[Training & Validation Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFgcR.png)

Last Epoch values (taken from tensorboard graph, some values I didn't save  from terminal):

```
Training Step: 17200+  | total loss: 1.7+ | time: 
| SGD | epoch: 500 | **loss: 0.5236** - acc: 0.8270 | val_loss: 1.30219 - val_acc: 0.6239 -- iter: 15855/15855
```

**GitHub:**

you are warmly welcome

https://github.com/tcsbmogarage/ED.git